# Saving KMeansModel on HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, k-means, bigdata

I want to save a KMeans Model on Hdfs. To do this I use the method save and create the otuput directory during runtime(See code). I get the Error Exception metadata already exists. How can I solve this problem?

```
  val lastUrbanKMeansModel = KMeansModel.load(spark, defaultPath + "UrbanRoad/201692918")
  val newUrbanKMeansObject = new KMeans()
    .setK(7)
    .setMaxIterations(20)
    .setInitialModel(lastUrbanKMeansModel)
  val vectorUrbanRoad = typeStreet.filter(k => k._2 == 1).map(_._1)

  if (!vectorUrbanRoad.isEmpty()) {

    val newUrbanModel = newUrbanKMeansObject.run(vectorUrbanRoad)
    newUrbanModel.save(spark, defaultPath + "UrbanRoad/" + 
      Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR).toString
      + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString + 
      Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString + 
      Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).toString)
  }
```